# What is the best way to encode features when clustering data?

Tags: machine-learning, python, unsupervised-learning, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with numerical and categorical features. I am trying to run a k-means algorithm to find clusters of data.

What is the best way to encode categorical features?

I have been doing one hot encoding but I guess that it can be easily improved.

Answer (score 0):

Try Hierarchical Clustering, Kmeans will not serve the purpose if you have categorical data.

Comment: For what I have seen in the other post one of the proposed ideas is to use K-Modes algorithm.